# how to convert dynamic Nested Json data into DataFrame (rtds-kafka) in Scala?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Actually I am trying to consume real time API through kafka and getting data in nested Json format. So, now I need that nested json data to be converted into dataframe (in Scala) .

I need that dynamically created nested json data to be converted into dataframe (in Scala)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you want your question to be answered more quickly, it's always best to try and make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That way, your question is more useful to you (quicker response) and the reviewers (easier to answer). Please edit your question to add the above.